# Python3 pip upgrade and install fails

Tags: caching, pip, typeerror, posix, python-3.6

I think I have a broken pip.
When I try to install a package or upgrade pip, I get the following error:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 69, in _build_session
    if options.cache_dir else None
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

Investigating this further I believe it is related to `pip cache`

```
pip cache
ERROR: pip cache commands can not function since cache is disabled.
```

Any thoughts?
I am trying to install a pip package.

Comment: Not a useful answer but it's worth noting [Python 3.6 is now end of life](https://peps.python.org/pep-0494/#lifespan) and unsupported. It might be worth updating python as that may fix this problem in the process.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's a , I am using `3.6.9`. I should do that ASAP, but in the meantime, I hope to resolve this pip issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use `--no-cache-dir` E.G. `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir`

Comment: This fixes the issue with manually installing one package, but not the bigger issue that is related to the cache being disabled.